# NSOutlineView Group spacing

Tags: objective-c, nsoutlineview, cellspacing

I'm working on a NSOutlineView (SourceList) and want the replace the current styling with my own to get a better look for my app. I've changed the default header and content cells with custom NSTableViewRows. This works fine.
But now I can see a space between the groups. These space is about 9 Pixels and I want to remove it. But I don't know how. Changing the cell spacing didn't help and I didn't find anything in the developer reference to do that.
Is there anybody who can give me a hint or a snippet? that would be great.

```
-----------------------
* Group 1
  - Item 1
  - Item 2
-----------------------
// this space should be changed
-----------------------
* Group 2
  - Item 3
  - Item 4
-----------------------
```

Thank you.
Alex

Comment: Isn't there anybody who had the same problem and could help me? I'm going crazy with that problem. Any help would be great! Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be just a try to get to the problem, not an answer, but stackoverflow doesn't let me comment because of my reputation.

Anyway, I remember to had weird behavior of [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the past.
Maybe the [setFloatsGroupRows:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setFloatsGroupRows%3a) will help you:

```
[myOutlineView setFloatsGroupRows:NO];
```

Please let me know.

Comment: This fixes an issue with the first header cell drawing incorrectly when the group is expanded. Thanks!