# NSOutlineView floating group rows padding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview, nstablerowview

I’ve set up my NSOutlineView to use floating group rows. And it works well, but the group rows which aren’t sticky all have extra top padding?

I see no configuration options to remove this. How can I set the height of the floating rows to be the actual height I have configured?

Comment: How is the height of the group rows configured? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: my issue is the same as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647198/nsoutlineview-group-spacing

Comment: So this question is a duplicate?

Comment: @Willeke it seems so, however that question is over 10yrs old.... should I close this question

Comment: If the answer to the linked question answers this question, yes.

Comment: no it does not unfortunately :(

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue?